# How many message Id should I cache to avoid duplicate messages in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

How many message Id should I cache to avoid duplicate messages in ActiveMQ? I want hand rolled solution. No more extra jar so please don't suggest Apache Camel etc.

EDIT
I have a ActiveMQ integrated with tomcat server. I maintain a cache of message Ids when server is running to weed out any duplicate messages. When I want to shutdown the server I want to persist this cache in RDBMS. Now this cache will become too big if server is online for long time. So, I want to persist message Ids of last few messages. Now what should be number of this message ids so I can safely assume that there want be any duplicate messages. I also don't want to purge all messages when server start by setting deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true".

Comment: This question is way too broad. You need to pose an actual problem you're having difficulty with. Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: I have updated my question with further details.

Answer (score 0):

Even though MessageID is not only way to ensure duplicates, better to look at some  payload attribute.

However, there is no way you can guarantee no duplicates unless you save all ID:s forever. Only reduce the probablility they will appear.

Example: Some technican restore files from a three year old backup tape that include messages that has already been delivered. Is it likely? Perhaps not. 100% safe? - No.

You know your organization best - how important this is and how many messages there are. Typically you reduce the risk a lot by keeping the ID:s for a short period to handle system restarts, system restores etc. Like a day or so.